# Relative positioning in TikZ with automatic nodes, so they do not overlap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am trying to create this diagram I made using the ipe drawing program, but want to do it in `TikZ` instead to compare the final quality.

[image]

But want to do it using relative positioning only, without having to use `at` coordinates or using hardcoded `xshift` and so on.   i.e. I want to tell tikz to put one node below and left of another node and have it come out right.

The problem is that as I add more nodes, they overlap each others.  Here is my attempt. The first two rows in the diagram look OK:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, text centered}   }  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node[block] (ode) {Differential equation};

\node[block] (firstOrder) [below left=of ode] {First order ode}; 
\node[block] (secondOrder) [below=of ode] {Second order ode}; 
\node[block](higherOrder) [below right=of ode] {Higher order ode}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The was not hard. Now the problem is when adding the next row. I am using only relative positioning.  Now it becomes this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw, text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, text centered}   }  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node[block] (ode) {Differential equation};

\node[block] (firstOrder) [below left=of ode] {First order ode}; 
\node[block] (secondOrder) [below=of ode] {Second order ode}; 
\node[block](higherOrder) [below right=of ode] {Higher order ode}; 

\node[block] (firstOrderLinear) [below left=of firstOrder] {First order linear in $y'$}; 
\node[block] (firstOrderNonLinear) [below right=of firstOrder] {First order none linear in $y'$}; 

\node[block]  (secondOrderLinear) [below left=of secondOrder]   {Linear second order ode}; 
\node[block]  (secondOrderNonLinear)  [below right=of secondOrder] {None linear second order ode}; 

\node[block] (higherOrderLinear) [below left=of higherOrder]   {Linear higher order ode}; 
\node[block] (higherOrderNonLinear) [below right=of higherOrder] {None linear higher order ode (not implemented)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You see that some of the nodes are on top of each others and not in right positions.

I thought that it will automatically arrange the nodes in the third row so they do not overlap and evenly distributed and I just needed to tell it relative position.

I know I can fix this by add explicit `xshift` with negative and positive values as needed. But the whole point is not to do this. I wanted this to be done automatically. Otherwise it will become very hard to manually position each node where it is supposed to be.

May be I am not doing this right.

What is the correct way to do this in tikz *without* using hard coded coordinate and any hardcoded numbers in the code? The final flow chart will be much more complicated than this, and I am trying to avoid using hard coded coordinates and numbers in it, and only use relative positioning if that is possible as this will make it easier to modify later on.

---

**Update**

As as workaround, I found this solution. I am not too unhappy with it as it does what I want: Which is to avoid using hardcoded coordinates and shifts for each node.  The solution is to use a row matrix for each layer of the chart. Here is the new code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw, text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, text centered}   }  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node[block] (ode) {Differential equation};

\matrix[column sep=4pt] at(0,-2) {
\node[block] (firstOrder) {First order ode}; &
\node[block] (secondOrder) {Second order ode}; &
\node[block](higherOrder) {Higher order ode};\\
};

\matrix[column sep=4pt] at(0,-4) {
\node[block] (firstOrderLinear) {First order linear in $y'$}; &
\node[block] (firstOrderNonLinear) {First order none linear in $y'$}; &
\node[block]  (secondOrderLinear)  {Linear second order ode}; &
\node[block]  (secondOrderNonLinear)   {None linear second order ode}; &
\node[block] (higherOrderLinear) {Linear higher order ode}; &
\node[block] (higherOrderNonLinear) {None linear higher order ode (not implemented)};\\
};

\draw[->] (ode)--(firstOrder);
\draw[->] (ode)--(secondOrder);
\draw[->] (ode)--(higherOrder);

\draw[->] (firstOrder)--(firstOrderLinear.north);
\draw[->] (firstOrder)--(firstOrderNonLinear.north);

\draw[->] (secondOrder)--(secondOrderLinear.north);
\draw[->] (secondOrder)--(secondOrderNonLinear.north);

\draw[->] (higherOrder)--(higherOrderLinear.north);
\draw[->] (higherOrder)--(higherOrderNonLinear.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives

[image]

I just needed to tell tikz location of each matrix. That is all. I need to work more to make the arrows look like in the IPE drawing, but this is minor issue.

But I still would like to know if there is a solution using only relative positioning.

---

**Update 2**

For completion, here is a solution using forest package. I think this one is simplest one

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, text centered}   }  

\newcommand\set[1]{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.8in}\raggedright%
#1
\end{minipage}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={edge+={->}} %to have arrow instead of just line
%
[\set{Differential equation}
   [\set{First order ode}
       [\set{First order linear in $y'$}]
       [\set{First order none linear in $y'$}]
   ]
   [\set{Second order ode}
       [\set{Linear second order ode}]
       [\set{None linear second order ode}]
   ]
   [\set{Higher order ode}
      [\set{Linear higher order ode}]
      [\set{None linear higher order ode (not implemented)}]
   ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use `for tree={forked edge,edge+={->}}` instead in the above, which gives this version

[image]

Another option is to change the `\set` command above to

```
\usepackage{fancybox}
\newcommand\set[1]{\shadowbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.8in}\raggedright%
#1
\end{minipage}}
}
```

And this gives

[image]

Comment: `forest`. It's a tree. This is what `forest` does.

Comment: @cfr I know and have used forest before, but was learning about relative positioning and wanted to see if I can do this without a package.

Comment: Or a matrix. I'm not sure what you want now. Because relative positioning won't lay out nodes avoiding overlaps, as far as I know. It's just another way of placing nodes. So if you say `above right=of a and b` or whatever, the node is placed at the (default as not specified) distances from `a` and `b` in the given directions. It isn't going to do anything to avoid overlapping nodes. If you want that 'without a package', you could try the graphing stuff. That's best with luatex, but it can give you something even without.

Comment: For a rooted true tree (no cycles), `forest` is the best. The manual is daunting but both the package's author and experienced users like @cfr are active here and there's always a solution. The [graphdrawing library `trees`](https://tikz.dev/gd-trees) does a similar thing but doesn't offer as much customization. Forest works by grabbing each node, typesetting it and measure the result. After all are measured it computes the proper position of all the nodes. Graphdrawing does basically the same but uses a PGF interface for that.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel There's also a quick-start guide on CTAN for `forest`: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest-quickstart. Note that I haven't used this myself, but I've seen others recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative positioning doesn't do what you think. It doesn't lay things out automatically to avoid overlaps. It is just a way of specifying where to put the node. Instead of specifying the position absolutely (which is still relative really, but it is relative to the coordinate system or the page), you specify the position relative to one or more other coordinates or nodes.

If you say 'put this 5cm above `a` and 1 cm left of `b`', the item will be placed 5cm above `a` and 1cm left of `b`. Ti*k*Z won't check whether that fits or avoids overlaps.

If you say 'put this right of `a`' that means 'put this the default distance right of `a` and 0pt above `a`'. So that's where Ti*k*Z will put it.

If you want a method which avoids overlaps etc., you need to use something which will do that e.g. `forest`, the graphing facilities of Ti*k*Z, a `matrix of nodes` or whatever.

In short, you are asking for a way to peel potatoes with a mallet and insisting you don't want to use a vegetable peeler when offered one.

Me, I'd use the vegetable peeler and find another use for the mallet:

[image: forest as vegetable peelrer]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge+={->},
    draw,
    anchor=child anchor,
    inner sep=0pt,
    align=C{5em},
  },
  forked edges,
  [Differential equation
    [First order ode
      [{First order linear in $y'$. $F(x,y,y')=0$}
      ]
      [{First order nonlinear in $y'$. ODE has form $f(x,y,y')$}
      ]
    ]
    [Second order ode
      [Linear second order ode
      ]
      [Nonlinear second order ode
      ]
    ]
    [Higher order ode
      [Linear higher order ode
      ]
      [Nonlinear higher order ode (not implemented)
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What was the code used to generate the diagram you show?  It looks nice.

Comment: @Nasser It's just `forest`. See edit above.